# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'inet_pton'

Tags: python, web.py

When I run this, or any webpy program I get the below error. I have tried different names, like `test.py`, and `server.py`. I have turned off ipv6 on my windows 7 computer, and nothing seams to fix this issue. how can I fix this error?

```
import web

urls = ( '/','Index',
)

class Index:
  def GET(self):
    return "Hello,world!"

app=web.application(urls,globals())

if __name__=="__main__":
  app.run()


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jay\workspace\test3\test2.py", line 13, in <module>
    app.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\application.py", line 313, in run
    return wsgi.runwsgi(self.wsgifunc(*middleware))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\wsgi.py", line 55, in runwsgi
    server_addr = validip(listget(sys.argv, 1, ''))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\net.py", line 108, in validip
    if validip6addr(ip): return (ip,port)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\web\net.py", line 33, in validip6addr
    socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET6, address)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'inet_pton'
```

Comment: https://github.com/kinverarity1/webpy/commit/3706180f4ee3f3ac7621a513fc7fd84ba851cf3e

need to change line 33 in net.py from:

    except socket.error:

to:

    except (socket.error, AttributeError):

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to change line 33 in net.py from: `except socket.error:` to `except (socket.error, AttributeError)`.

More information [here](https://github.com/kinverarity1/webpy/commit/3706180f4ee3f3ac7621a513fc7fd84ba851cf3e).

Answer (score 4):

1. Install `win` `inet` `pton` using terminal or cmd
2. Run `pip install win-inet-pton`
3. In the project code write: `import win_inet_pton`

Comment: Thank you. This helped me a great deal.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the line 33 in net.py from:

```
except socket.error:
```

to

```
except (socket.error, AttributeError)
```

perfectly works for me.